# Google Earth loads KML 2.2 but not Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

The [Google maps script](http://rioleo.org/dev/gps/data/map.php) I have seems to load the [example KML from Chicago](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml) files fine, but when [I add my own](http://rioleo.org/dev/gps/data/2013-01-09T04-36-27Z.kml), it fails. The KML standard is 2.2 - why doesn't Google Maps manage to read it (Google Earth seems to work fine)? When I tried to [validate the file](http://kmlvalidator.com) it said there were some errors - is there any way around it given that this is an output I get from an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[geoxml3, KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/2013-01-09T04-36-27Z_kml.xml) and [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2F2013-01-09T04-36-27Z_kml.xml&hl=en&ll=35.674903,139.741824&spn=0.009692,0.013797&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=m&z=16) load your kml for me.  My server doesn't support KML with the .kml extension, just as XML with the .xml extension because [it isn't configured for the KML/KMZ MIME types](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server), you might have the same problem on your server.

See [this issue on the Google Maps API v3 issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4776) regarding the "spikes" on the line.

Another option would be to to see what [KmlLayer.getStatus()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) returns ([Kml Status:DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://rioleo.org/dev/gps/data/2013-01-09T04-36-27Z.kml)).  The [cta.kml example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml) returns Kml Status:OK.